# Rendering HTTP inside HTTPS request

Tags: php, apache, http, https

I've installed Icinga 2 monitoring tool with [Graphite](https://github.com/findmypast/icingaweb2-module-graphite#what-it-looks-like) support.
Graphite basically provides graphs based on metrics that Icinga 2 produces.

It works over HTTP, but whenever I enable HTTPS for my Apache VHOST, it stops working.

The following link is an example of what is requested.

https://monitoring.example.com/icingaweb2/graphite?graphite_url=**http%253A%252F%252Fgraphite.example.com**%252Frender%252F%253F%2526target%253Dicinga2.hostname.services.ping6.ping6.perfdata.rta.value%2526source%253D0%2526width%253D600%2526height%253D400%2526colorList%253D049BAF%2526lineMode%253Dconnected

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName monitoring.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://monitoring.example.com/icingaweb2

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName monitoring.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/monitoring.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/monitoring.example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_CA_Bundle.crt

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    Alias "/icingaweb2" "/usr/share/icingaweb2/public"

    <Directory "/usr/share/icingaweb2/public">
        Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        SetEnv ICINGAWEB_CONFIGDIR "/etc/icingaweb2"

        EnableSendfile Off

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteBase /icingaweb2/
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
            DirectoryIndex error_norewrite.html
            ErrorDocument 404 /error_norewrite.html
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>           
</VirtualHost>
```

I've enabled "LogLevel debug" for the vhost, but there are no errors. HTTP resp code always equals to 200.

URL gets encoded by the following piece of PHP code:

```
$url = Url::fromPath('graphite', array(
            'graphite_url' => urlencode($largeImgUrl)
        ));
```

Please give me a hint on what might be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible to mix HTTP and HTTPS. Configuring graphite.example.com to work over HTTPS solved the problem.

Google Chrome console says:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://monitoring.example.com/icingaweb2/monitoring/service/show?host=c…600%2526height%253D400%2526colorList%253D049BAF%2526lineMode%253Dconnected'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://graphite.example.com/render/?&target=icinga2.camhpcvm02.services.…ht=120&hideAxes=true&lineWidth=2&hideLegend=true&colorList=049BAF&from=-1h'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>   show?host=camhpcvm02&service=ssh:1